# Is it possible to use querySelector() on a dynamically created element?

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm using appendHtml() in a loop to dynamically add li elements (with unique IDs in the string) to a ul. When I need to access these dynamically created li elements by their IDs to, for example, create nested lists, querySelector() returns null. If I should be able to do this, then there could very well be bugs in my code. But I want to make sure this is the case.

Comment: Please add the code that you're referring to. And yes, you can use `querySelector` to find any element in the DOM, regardless of how it's created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter how elements are added, if the are part of the DOM `querySelector` can find them.