# JavaScript, enable queryselector on dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have `DIV` element in body and i copy that element to enable adding more elements to database but when i execute script that looks like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document.body).on('change','.jobType',function(){
    var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    select = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getpart',
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            part_id : value,
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            wrapper = select.closest('.wrapper');
            console.log(v, select);
            inputPrice = wrapper.querySelector('.jobPrice')
            console.log(inputPrice, data.Part.price);
            inputPrice.value = data.Part.price;
        }
    });
});
});
```

var `wrapper` is null because is added to DOM dynamically, is there a way to use `document.querySelector()` on newly added element ?

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: also where is the `wrapper` element added and when

Comment: also change `select = this;` to `var select = this;`

Comment: if at the time of execution of `select.closest('.wrapper')` if there is an ancestor `wrapper` for the `select` element then that should work....

Comment: are you sure about `$(document.body).on('change','.jobType',...`?? it's quiet unclear, But as i can understand, you have to select elements after they are added to the DOM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26396084/5247200: It doesn't matter how elements are added, if the are part of the DOM querySelector can find them.

Comment: Given `select = this`, then *select* is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. You need `select = $(this)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added jquery statements to you existing code. If you have jQuery you can use it.

Changes:

1) `var select = $(this);`

2) `var value = select.val();`

3) `var wrapper = select.closest('.wrapper');`

4) `var inputPrice = wrapper.find('.jobPrice')`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document.body).on('change','.jobType',function(){
    var select = $(this);
    var value = select.val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getpart',
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            part_id : value,
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            var wrapper = select.closest('.wrapper');
            console.log(select);
            var inputPrice = wrapper.find('.jobPrice')
            console.log(inputPrice, data.Part.price);
            inputPrice.val(data.Part.price);
        }
    });
  });
});
```